# Joining to Same Column but Getting No Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables.

```
Table1
ID    Text

Table2
ID    ParentID    Text
```

I am trying to join to the same table twice using 2 different columns. I want all the rows where Table1.ID = Table2.ID as well as all the rows where Table1.ID = Table2.ParentID.  I've tried the following but it returns no rows.  When I run the script below in two different select statements each with one of the joins only, I get the result I want but not in the same select statement. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 1
JOIN Table2 2 
    on 2.ID = Table1.ID
JOIN Table2 22 
    on 22.ParentID = Table1.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only getting the records where Table 1 is both a Parent ID and an ID... maybe you want:

```
SELECT 
* FROM Table 1
JOIN Table2 2 on 2.ID = Table1.ID
UNION
SELECT 
* FROM Table 1
JOIN Table2 22 on 22.ParentID = Table1.ID
```

Or potentially UNION ALL?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that was the issue.  Your select statement pulls in just what I need. Thank you so much.  I ultimately have to update these values.  Is it possible to update using a union or should I just use two seperate update statements?

Comment: You can only update one table at a time, unless you mean update a 3rd table using this select, in which case you could.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TABLE1, 
    TABLE2 
WHERE 
    TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID 
    OR 
    TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ParentID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your aliasing is a little off.

Give this a go:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 1
JOIN Table2 2 
    on 2.ID = 1.ID
JOIN Table2 22
    on 22.ParentID = 1.ID
```

You may still get an error on the `SELECT *` by not having an alias there... I suggest doing `SELECT 1.*`, or even doing `SELECT 1.myColumn, 1.myColumn2` etc...